# How do I find out what filling up the space in dev/sda2 using ssh command

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, hosting, dedicated-server

My apologies if the question is vague and too naive. I am totally new with the Linux commands.

We have a dedicated server with [OVH Cloud](https://www.ovh.co.uk/) and have several sites hosted there. Our server is running out of space.

This is what I got by running `df -h` in the command prompt after connecting with the server via ssh

[image]

I have little to no experience with Linux shell command. How do I figure out what is filling up the space and where the folder is located. How do I go to Home directory?

My assumption is the server is running cache . But I an't figure out where these cache is getting stored. I am not an expert with server and system administration. Please treat me as total novice in this sector.

appreciate your help

Comment: You aren't running out of space, you have 3.2TB available. What is the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: running out of space in dev/sd2.  We cannot access the whm path when the dev/sd2 is filled up . Last week disk usage on dev/sd2 was 100%

Comment: Ah! I see, sorry I misunderstood.